# GeoServer Monitoring Extention didnt create Request table on oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, monitoring, geoserver

After I installed GeoServer 2.10 , I Installed Monitoring Extension and Hibernate Extension. After that I modified monitoring.properties file  like below

```
    # the storage mode, one of: memory, hibernate
# Note: hibernate mode requires the hibernate extension
storage=hibernate

# the monitor mode, one of: live, history
mode=history
```

And After that I modified db.properties file like below

```
# sample configuration for oracle
#[instance]
driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port\:instance
username=username
password=password
```

when I restart GeoServer and looked to Monitoring page after some requests. Page gave me error like that

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this container for rendering: [Page class = org.geoserver.monitor.web.ActivityPage, id = 8, render count = 1]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1580)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3877)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:801)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:949)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1017)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalPrepareForRender(Component.java:2215)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.internalPrepareForRender(Page.java:242)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2304)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:865)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
```

And Here is GeoServer Log

```
could not execute query
select requestdat0_.ID as ID0_, requestdat0_.STATUS as STATUS0_, requestdat0_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY0_, requestdat0_.PATH as PATH0_, requestdat0_.BODY as BODY0_, requestdat0_.QUERY_STRING as QUERY6_0_, requestdat0_.BODY_CONTENT_TYPE as BODY7_0_, requestdat0_.BODY_CONTENT_LENGTH as BODY8_0_, requestdat0_.SERVER_HOST as SERVER9_0_, requestdat0_.INTERNAL_SERVER_HOST as INTERNAL10_0_, requestdat0_.HTTP_METHOD as HTTP11_0_, requestdat0_.START_TIME as START12_0_, requestdat0_.END_TIME as END13_0_, requestdat0_.TOTAL_TIME as TOTAL14_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_ADDRESS as REMOTE15_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_HOST as REMOTE16_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_USER as REMOTE17_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_USER_AGENT as REMOTE18_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_COUNTRY as REMOTE19_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_CITY as REMOTE20_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_LAT as REMOTE21_0_, requestdat0_.REMOTE_LON as REMOTE22_0_, requestdat0_.SERVICE as SERVICE0_, requestdat0_.OPERATION as OPERATION0_, requestdat0_.SUB_OPERATION as SUB25_0_, requestdat0_.OWS_VERSION as OWS26_0_, requestdat0_.CONTENT_TYPE as CONTENT27_0_, requestdat0_.RESPONSE_LENGTH as RESPONSE28_0_, requestdat0_.ERROR_MESSAGE as ERROR29_0_, requestdat0_.EXCEPTION_STACK_TRACE as EXCEPTION30_0_, requestdat0_.RESPONSE_STATUS as RESPONSE31_0_, requestdat0_.HTTP_REFERER as HTTP32_0_, requestdat0_.MINX as MINX0_, requestdat0_.MINY as MINY0_, requestdat0_.MAXX as MAXX0_, requestdat0_.MAXY as MAXY0_, requestdat0_.CRS as CRS0_ from REQUEST requestdat0_ where requestdat0_.STATUS in (? , ? , ?)
```

and

```
2017-02-03 11:18:09,773 WARN [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
2017-02-03 11:18:09,774 ERROR [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

when I looked to oracle I didnt see Request table.

Comment: Which user are you using to connect to the database to check whether the request table is exists or not and in the db.properties?

Comment: I use a db user for connect to db. Request table does not exist and here is db.properties 
driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port\:instance
username=username
password=password

Comment: when ı created Request table manually , this error appeared in log file " Invalid column type: getLong not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor"